# Angular method call inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Here is the plunk [githubviewer](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZC7xJdHpnYutbhD0GzkR?p=info) am hoping someone would help. According to the tutorial am following thro' am supposed to get a popup window by calling the controller  `countDownController`  
Here is a snippet of the JS file

```
getstartedapp.controller('countDownController', function countDownController($scope, $interval, $window) {
    $scope.countdown = 5;
    startCountdown;
    var startCountdown = function () {
        $window.alert(1);
    };
    var decrementFunction = function () {
        $scope.countdown = -1
        if ($scope.countdown < 1) {
            $scope.search($scope.username);
        }
    };
});
```

and here is the html that it is loading

```
<div ng-controller="countDownController">
    {{ countdown }}
</div>
```

when the page is loaded. Any thoughts on what I might be missing?? Thanks.

Comment: please make the question self-contained

Comment: if you intended to call `startCountdown` then you need brackets: `startCountdown()`

Comment: That throws me an error. I did try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `startCountdown()` instead of `startCountdown`. In the plnkr, you also have to put that call after your function definition.

See **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mt7fh54A3F2UB61Rv71?p=preview)**

```
getstartedapp.controller('countDownController', function countDownController($scope, $interval,$window) {
    $scope.countdown = 5;

    var startCountdown = function () {
        $window.alert(1);
    };
    var decrementFunction = function () {
        $scope.countdown = -1
        if ($scope.countdown < 1) {
            $scope.search($scope.username);
        }
    };
    startCountdown();
});
```